# '@layer' is not supported by Chrome, Chrome Android, Edge, Opera, Samsung Internet

Tags: tailwind-css

#### Problem

Hello everyone, I am new to Tailwind CSS, and it keeps showing me this error that, in turn, prevents any of my code from displaying any CSS.

I have tried opening the code in different browsers, yet there is no change. I don't understand why it works for some people but not for me.

#### VScode Warning: `@layer`

[image: vscode warning message to @layer]

#### Browser Error: `sm:`

[image: browser error message to sm:]

Comment: These are just warnings from your editor and can be ignored, the code should work when configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for responsive `sm:`  is incorrect. There is a space after the colon that causes error and prevents the CSS from being displayed. Below is the correct syntax.

```
@apply sm:flex-1;

...

@apply sm:px-16;
```